# Recursively counting occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I was asked to recursively find how many times `String b` appears in `String a` recursively. I've gotten to the point where I can find the number of instances, but only when `String a` contains no whitespace at all, and despite using a continuous string to build the recursion model, I was asked to use a sentence with implicit whitespace for `String a` and a word for `String b`. Whenever I try running the code with whitespace it returns `1` all the time. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

```
static int countSubstrig(String str1,
        String str2) {
    int n1 = str1.length();
    int n2 = str2.length();

    if (n1 == 0 || n1 < n2) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (str1.substring(0, n2).equals(str2)) {
        return countSubstrig(str1.substring(n2 - 1),str2) + 1;
    }
    return countSubstrig(str1.substring(n2 - 1),
            str2);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str1 = "ijustneedforneed",
            str2 = "need";
    System.out.println(countSubstrig(str1,
            str2));
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. It's not clear why whitespace/not has any influence on this code.

Comment: I'm suspicious as to the `str1.substring(n2 - 1)` - why `n2 - 1`?

Comment: why recursively?

Comment: If string 1 was `"ababab"` and string 2 was `"aba"` what would be the result?

Comment: @MauricePerry  instructor is trying to walk us through recursion basics instead of using iteration to solve

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively using `indexOf` to find the next position in `str1` where `str2` occurs:

```
static int countSubstrig(String str1, String str2) {
  int pos = str1.indexOf(str2);
  if (pos < 0) return 0;
  return 1 + countSubstrig(str1.substring(pos + str2.length()), str2);
}
```

This assumes that `str2` is not empty, and that you don't want to consider overlapping occurrences.

If you want to allow overlapping occurrences, change `pos + str2.length()` to `pos + 1`.

You can also do it more efficiently, without creating the substrings:

```
static int countSubstrig(String str1, String str2) {
  return countSubstrig(str1, 0, str2);
}

static int countSubstrig(String str1, int s, String str2) {
  int pos = str1.indexOf(str2, s);
  if (pos < 0) return 0;
  return 1 + countSubstrig(str1, pos + str2.length(), str2);
}
```